# How to prevent XSS attacks in api mode of Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've read an article about preventing XSS attacks. it explained, Rails itself prevents some attacks. actually Rails uses **ERB::Util#html_escape** function to escape HTML entities.
`<b>Hello <%= params[:name] %></b>` 
If the above is attacked with `?name=<script>alert(1)</script>`, the output will be as follows: 
`<b> Hello &lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;gt; </b>`  
But, when I pass this `name` in API mode, it doesn't work.

**POSTMAN**
`url?name=<script>alert(1)</script>`

**Rails App**
`params[:name]` 
the output will be `"<script>alert(1)</script>"`. 
Does it have any config for working correctly in API mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an attack to receive data like that. It's an attack to *display it*.

By default Rails escapes within the HTML context, and only within the HTML context, so when you do:

```
<p><%= params[:name] %></p>
```

You'll see the escaped version that's rendered harmless. The only way around this is if you go out of your way to declare it safe with `html_safe`, which you wouldn't do unless you're sure it is safe.

If you have an API-style app with no front-end at all, congratulations, you're immune to XSS attacks. Your clients, however, will need to take precautions to ensure they properly escape any content for the appropriate context in which it's presented.

In other words, Rails won't and shouldn't care unless HTML is being displayed.

Remember, the parameter itself is never altered, it's just escaped before being displayed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, may explain how to control parameters in API mode? for example, how to check all of the parameters to be valid.
actually, I know that we can use regex for ```name```. but think I have a lot of parameters, and I wanna check all of them be valid.

Comment: @HosseinSafari If you're up to trying something different, you can take a look at the `dry-rails` gem, it has some very nice functionality to validate params https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-rails/0.1/#safe-params

Comment: Usually that's done with model validations. You can also do it with validators like [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org) for a JSON API.

Comment: Thanks, I wanna save the value of ```name``` into the database. I don't want to save the value of ```<script>alert(1)</script>```. and I wanna return an error for this value. what is the best gem for validating it?

Comment: There's no gem per-se, you just set up validations in your model. This is what [`validates format: ...`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format) is all about.